# Lim inf of sum of functions

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, probability-limit-theorems, supremum-and-infimum

When is the lim inf of sum of two real valued functions equal to the sum of their individual lim inf?
That is, I am looking for condition on $f$ and $g$ under which $\liminf\limits_{x \rightarrow \bar{x}} (f(x) + g(x)) = \liminf\limits_{x \rightarrow \bar{x}} f(x) + \liminf\limits_{x \rightarrow \bar{x}} g(x).$

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition is: $g=\psi\circ f$ where $\psi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an increasing function. Indeed, in this case a sequence $x_n$ that satisfies $\lim f(x_n)=\liminf f$ also satisfies $\lim g(x_n)=\liminf g$, and therefore 
$$\liminf (f+g)\le \lim (f(x_n)+g(x_n))= \liminf f+\liminf g$$
(the converse inequality being true for all $f,g$).

I would not expect any non-tautological necessary and sufficient condition here.

Comment: Hi, could I ask: what if f and g are continuous?